# How to access Windows password and userid?

Tags: java, windows

I have an executable JAR file (application compiled in java) . I scheduled  it to start running using Windows Scheduler . So it fires everyday from my desktop at 9PM.

The JAR uses my current Windows userid and password . However , when password expires , I have to recompile the JAR file because I have to change the password string in the app  .

**Since the Runnable JAR is triggered by Windows Task Scheduler , I hope there is a way to pass along my password from Windows Task Scheduler to my Runnable JAR everyday .**

Is there any way my application could get access to my Windows password and get keep updated ?

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {


        for (int i=0; i< args.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(args[i]);
        }

        System.exit(0);
```

Comment: I highly doubt your password is stored in plaintext anywhere within Windows... That would be a **major** security vulnerability.

Comment: I know it is not stored somewhere. But since my executable JAR is triggered with the Windows Task Scheduler , I think there might be a way to get the authentication from the Task Scheduler to JAR

Comment: If the Scheduled task is running under a specific user, why does it need to know that users Username and Password?

Comment: Try adding command line arguments when invoking the jar, you can then parse the arguments within the running JAR.

Comment: I know a Windows service can run under a specific user account. Can't the same be done with the task scheduler?

Comment: Thank you. How can I get the command line arguments . What code lines should I add to my code ?

Comment: Parse the String array passed into your main method, they contain the command line arguments.

Comment: I tried to print it to console . I updated my question

Comment: And? What were the results? Do you feel they were useful? Just dumping a code snippet into your question, that is unrelated to the bigger question, hardly helps anyone...

Comment: Keep in mind, this still means you have to update your Scheduled task with your updated password every time it changes. And that you are now storing your password in plain text in the Windows Scheduler compared to a generated jar. There isn't a way have Scheduler pass *your* password to the job through some sort of configuration variable.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way my application could get access to my Windows password and get keep updated ?

No. In the first place there is no Windows API. In the second place Windows almost certainly doesn't store the password, but rather a hash of he password. In the third place Windows wouldn't have given it to you in the first place.